# sharp Prebuilt libvips 8.10.5 binaries are not yet available for darwin-arm64v8

Tags: node.js, macos, zsh

In node js I am installing all package.json dependencies using yarn install command in **mac**. my node version is 12.0.0.

Please help help me if I need to install anything additional.

I have installed in **mac**

step 1) zsh
step 2) NVM
step 3) node 12.0.0
step 4) npm install -g yarn

in Visual studio code run command **yarn install**

error: -

```
error /Users/poorna/MY_Project/my-backend/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/poorna/MY_Project/my-backend/node_modules/sharp
Output:
info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.10.5/libvips-8.10.5-darwin-arm64v8.tar.br
ERR! sharp Prebuilt libvips 8.10.5 binaries are not yet available for darwin-arm64v8
info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.0.0 | darwin | arm64
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/poorna/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/poorna/MY_Project/my-backend/node_modules/sharp/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/poorna/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/poorna/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/poorna/.node-gyp/12.0.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/poorna/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/poorna/.node-gyp/12.0.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/poorna/MY_Project/my-backend/node_modules/sharp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/node_modules/node-addon-api/nothing.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/nothing.a
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/libtool: archive library: Release/nothing.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
../src/common.cc:24:10: fatal error: 'vips/vips8' file not found
#include <vips/vips8>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/poorna/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:256:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/poorna/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/bin/node" "/Users/poorna/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/poorna/MY_Project/my-backend/node_modules/sharp
```

Comment: I would suggest to install `nvm` for an easier switch between `nodejs` version.

Comment: Yes I installed NVM and by using NVM installed node version 12.0.0. This specific version i need to use.

Comment: Install a lower version, `sharp@0.22.1` for node v12. Found an issue of this [Enhancement: add support for Node 12](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1668)

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands

```bash
brew install --build-from-source gcc

xcode-select install

brew install vips
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all suggested solution but nothing worked.

what fixed this for me :
If someone is facing the issue with React Native & M1 mac, make sure you do not have multiple node installation.
in my case I first installed node using pkg from website later on, to use multiple versions I installed NVM which overwrited first installation.

check if this is the case with you.

First delete all node versions installed using nvm
go inside ***/Users//.nvm/versions/node*** folder and delete all node version folders.
now you don't have any node version installed using nvm.

then try `node -v` command to check if this still shows you node version
if yes then our case is same.

delete that version too by googling command for it then only use nvm to install node versions.

now try `npm install or yarn install`